# Class, __init__, global list.append(self)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

Допустим у меня есть класс `Mob` и есть дочерний класс `Goat`, в котором весь `__init__` класса `Mob`, где-то в далеке у меня есть два списка: один с потоками, другой с координатами этих мобов. Два вопроса, как мне реализовать динамический список с добавляемыми постоянно потоками? Я правильно делаю дополнение списка `mobs` в `__init__`?

```
class Mob:
    global mobs # <== ?
    global threads # <== ?

    def __init__(self, x, y, health, mod='y'):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.health = health
        self.mod = mod

        # Так или нет?
        mobs.append[[self.x, self.y]]
        threads.append[] # ????

class Goat(Mob):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mobs = []
    threads = []
```

Делаю игру в консоли, столкнулся  с проблемой добавления мобов. Для каждого нужен поток, потому что все двигаются по заданным параметрам.

**P.S** Для потоков использую конструкцию `name = threading.Thread(target=def, name='example')`

Answer (score 0):

Ключевое слово `global` работает только внутри функций (методов). Но в примере из вопроса ключевое `global` вообще не нужно, т.к. внутри методов значения переменных не перезаписываются (подчеркну, `global` нужно только если значение глобальной переменной перезаписывается), а выполняется метод объекта, записанного в переменной. Но инициализация должна выполняться вне блока `if __name__ == '__main__':`, т.к. если файл будет подключен через `import`, то инициализация глобальных переменных не произойдет, и при создании объектов будет попытка выполнить метод `append` у неинициализированной переменной.

Но вообще в коде в ООП стиле `global` не нужно практически никогда. Я бы сделал по-другому:

Для полного списка мобов лучше использовать не глобальную переменную, а поле класса. Если каждому мобу однозначно соответствует свой поток, то поток должен быть полем объекта, а не храниться где-то отдельно.

```
class Mob:
    mobs = []  # полный список объектов-мобов

    def __init__(self, x, y, health, mod='y'):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.health = health
        self.mod = mod
        self.thread = <что-то>

        self.mobs.append(self)  # лучше добавлять сам объект, а не только координаты


class Goat(Mob):
    def __init__(self, x, y, health, mod='y'):
        super().__init__(x, y, health, mod='y')
```

Список мобов будет доступен через `Mob.mobs` или `Goat.mobs` (вне объектов класса `Mob` и дочерних классов), `self.mobs` (внутри методов объектов класса `Mob` или дочерних).